# Программно создать ODBC объект в Access

Tags: vba, access, office

Подскажите, как программно через VBA можно создать объект ODBC в Access, так что бы он отображался в меню, где находятся все остальные объекты(таблицы, запросы и т п)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм...
Нашел решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316669/how-to-programmatically-create-an-odbc-linked-table-to-a-sql-server-view-and-hav):

```
Dim connStr As String
connStr = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" + serverName + ";DATABASE=" + dbName + ";LANGUAGE=us_english;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=No"

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC", connStr , acTable, "Название таблицы в MS SQL", "Как будет называться таблица в Access", False, True
```

Comment: @4per, да, чет я лишнее накопировал в ответ самому себе, так как мне это нужно как раз было для импорта.